# Increase Heap Size for Data Loader Started from dataloader.bat Windows Batch File

Tags: data-loader

For the older version of data loader this was possible by following the guide below:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329565&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

From the desktop icon right click and modify:

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\Java\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms1024m -Xmx1256m -Dappdata.dir="C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\dataloader-26.0.0-uber.jar"*

The newer version (47.0) of data loader kicks off using a Windows batch file.

How do I go about allocating more memory to the JVM which Data Loader runs in?

I am using Zulu OpenJDK version 11 for Windows per the documentation from Salesforce below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_install_windows.htm

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the article you link says that:

> Newer Dataloader versions (45 and up) that use Zulu Java manage heap size differently and should not need to do this.

Are you certain that this is what you need to do? What are you doing that's bringing a memory error that you believe will be resolved by this?

That said, it's straightforward enough to pass those memory allocation options in the batch file. The `-Xmsn` and `-Xmxn` options to set the minimum and maximum size of the memory allocation are [also available in OpenJDK](https://linux.die.net/man/1/java-java-1.7.0-openjdk):

> **-Xmsn** Specify the initial size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must be a multiple of 1024 greater than 1MB. Append
>   the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate
>   megabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system
>   configuration. For more information, see HotSpot Ergonomics @
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
>   Examples:
>          -Xms6291456
>          -Xms6144k
>          -Xms6m
>
> **-Xmxn** Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the
>   letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes.
>   The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.
>   For more information, see HotSpot Ergonomics @
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
>   Examples:
>          -Xmx83886080
>          -Xmx81920k
>          -Xmx80m

So, use VS Code (or Notepad or other text editor) to open the .bat file that the desktop shortcut points to (C:\Users\[*username*]\dataloader\[*API version*]\dataloader.bat by default). Find the line that runs Java with the JAR file:

```
"%ZULU_JAVA_HOME%\java" -jar dataloader-48.0.0-uber.jar salesforce.config.dir=configs
```

and add your memory allocation options before the `-jar` parameter:

```
"%ZULU_JAVA_HOME%\java" -Xms1024m -Xmx1256m -jar dataloader-48.0.0-uber.jar salesforce.config.dir=configs
```

Save the batch file, and run Dataloader from the desktop shortcut.